# How to add groups(security group) to a storage account in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there any ways to add the security group to a given storage account? Nothing found from MS documents from net.

Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign security group a role in your Storage Account.

Login to Azure Portal --> Go to your Storage Account --> Click on Access Control (IAM) --> Click on Add Role Assignment

Now select the role you want to assign to the security group

Go to Members tab --> Click on Select Members and add your security group --> Click on Review and Assign

Answer (score 0):

Storage Account > IAM > Add > select role > select member > Create

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003556)

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can manage each Azure resource with the IAM and then assign the relevant RBAC. In addition, note that the roles are inherited which means that if You'll assign it to a whole resource group, all of the resources in it will have the same role. This example relevant if you have a lot of storage accounts and you don't want to add permissions on by one.